# Move Directories from Subdirectory to Parent

Tags: windows, command-line

I need to move several directories from their current directory (directoryA) to directoryA's parent folder (parent).

Current setup:

```
parent\directoryA\2016a
parent\directoryA\2016b
parent\directoryA\2016c
```

Like to change to:

```
parent\2016a
parent\2016b
parent\2016c
```

And I need to do this for ~100 parents, all in one directory.

I think that I can do this with 'for', not sure how.

Thank you.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear if you want all directories from `parent\directoryA` to be moved. But assuming that that is the case Robocopy would do the job just fine.

The command to use can be (when the command is at `directoryA`):

```
robocopy *.* . .\.. /E /MOVE
```