# Remove subdirectory from path and promote files to parent

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of files which contain within their path, a duplicated folder (in the following examples `bar`). I would like to remove this directory and move any contents in contains into the parent. To use search and replace as a metaphor, I would like to replace `/foo/` with `/` in the path.

Initial State:

```
foo/bar/some_file.txt
foo/another_file.txt
quux/bar/yet_another_file.txt
```

Goal:

```
foo/some_file.txt
foo/another_file.txt
quux/yet_another_file.txt
```

I have a preference for solving this with bash, but would be open to any solution that doesn't have any dependencies and will work on Linux.

---

In case this is helpful for anyone who stumbles upon this thread, there is [an existing answer for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1170773/move-directories-from-subdirectory-to-parent) using robocopy.

Comment: This is pretty straightforward with `bash` Parameter Expansion: what have you tried? We are not a script-writing service, but we will help when you get stuck.

Comment: @AFH I tried renaming the files with krename, but was only able to get substitutions to work in the file name (in contrast to the path). I feel like xargs + sed could somehow be used to get where I want to go, but don't really know where to start. I'm happy to read if you'd point me in the right direction.

Comment: If `fn` contains the file name, then `${fn%%/*}` is the first element of the path (removing the first '/' and all beyond), and `${fn##*/}` is the file name (removing all up to the last '/'). So you simply need to create an `mv` target from these elements; you don't need external programs for the name processing.

Comment: Will this work? `mv foo/bar/*.* foo/*.*`

Comment: @Biswapriyo It would if everything were in `foo`, but that wouldn't handle the files in the `quux` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up solving it like this:

```
for iteration_path in ${1}/*; do
  if [[ ! -z $iteration_path ]]; then
    mv "${iteration_path}"/bar/* "${iteration_path}";
    rmdir "${iteration_path}"/bar;
  fi
done
```

If anyone can expand on AFH's suggestions about [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe), I'd be interested if that is a more elegant solution.